# Executing a PHP function in another file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've been looking through past responses and stealing code but nothing seems to work! When a script loads, I'm trying to execute a PHP function in an seperate PHP file. I get the alert message that it was submitted BUT looking at the console, none of my console messages are appearing.

I read that the AJAX function requires a response back, that is why I added the echo('Text'). I am using a Google Browser.
I am not big on jsQuery, javascript or AJAX. PHP and HTML is my stronger side.

In my HTML code:

```
<body onload = "Start()">

<script>
    var Start = function() {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'MainRoutine.php?action=Startfunc',
            data: {func: "Startfunc"},
            success: function(response) {
                $('.result_Postme').text(response);
            }
        })
        alert("Form submitted successfully.\n"); // this is working!
    });
}
</script>
```

In my MainRoutine.php file:

```
if (isset($_POST['func']) && ($_POST['func'] == 'Startfunc')) { 
    ChromePhp::log("Start Handle"); // the expected console message
    echo('Text'); // not sure why I'm doing this...
    Start(); // this is the function I'm trying to execute!
}else{
    ChromePhp::log("Error"); // not even this one displays
}

function Start() {
    echo('Text');  // not sure why I'm doing this either
}
```

I'm not trying to pass any variables to the PHP "Start()" function, I just want to execute it!

Comment: Do you see the request on Network tab in DevTools?

Comment: You are sending the key `action` but looking for it as `func` in $_POST

Comment: Your alert function is simply showing you that your Start() call was executed. If you want to see that the AJAX call was successful, you can put that alert inside the success block after $('.result_Postme').text(response);  It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish other than maybe logging that a page loaded (which your server logs would tell you)

Comment: And as Andrei pointed out, a browser's developer tools are the way to figure this out.  You can look at the console and see if you're getting js errors, make sure that jQuery is properly loaded, and watch the network traffic to see if the ajax call is happening, and if it is, see what the response is - most likely an error...

Comment: in your ajax function, you are sending a key called **func** with a value of **'Startfunc'**. so  that means in your if statement you'll only need to check for one condition which is `if (isset($_POST['func'] == 'Startfunc')){....}` your url can just be `url: 'MainRoutine.php'`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `action` as a parameter in your code. You are checking `func` as in `$_POST`.

Please see the below is correct code:

```
<script>
    var Start = function() {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'MainRoutine.php?action=Startfunc',
            data: {func: "Startfunc"},
            success: function(response) {
                $('.result_Postme').text(response);
            }
        })
        alert("Form submitted successfully.\n"); // this is working!
    });
}
</script>
```

And in your `MainRoutine.php` file:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']=='Startfunc'){ 
    ChromePhp::log("Start Handle"); // the expected console message
    echo('Text'); // not sure why I'm doing this...
    Start(); // this is the function I'm trying to execute!
}else{
    ChromePhp::log("Error"); // not even this one displays
}

function Start() {
    echo('Text');  // not sure why I'm doing this either
}
```